# "'OpenGL/OpenGL.h' file not found" triggered by GPUImage cocoapod in my iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, gpuimage, cocoapods

Despite the fact that I'm installing it in a iOS project, it looks like GPUImage is demanding a MacOSX library. I'm getting this error:

```
MyProject/Pods/GPUImage/framework/Source/Mac/GPUImageContext.h:2:9: 'OpenGL/OpenGL.h'
file not found
```

How can I fix this? Why is it trying to include a mac framework "`framework/Source/Mac`"? Is there something causing CocoaPods to think I'm trying to compile for a OSX target?

My podfile:

```
platform :ios, '6.1'

pod 'Mantle', :head
pod 'Archimedes', :head
pod 'ReactiveCocoa', :head
pod 'GPUImage', '~> 0.1.0'
```

Comment: There are two Xcode projects in the GPUImage base directory, one for the Mac and one for iOS. You sure CocoaPods is grabbing the right project? I can confirm that the iOS project builds cleanly from the repository as of right now.

Comment: @BradLarson I'm not sure it's grabbing the right project. The podspec is [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/GPUImage/0.1.0/GPUImage.podspec). I don't see any conditionals in the podspec so maybe its trying to compile both. Can you identify the problem in the podspec?

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing about CocoaPods, so I'm not the one to ask about that. You might want to contact one of those who submitted the podspec there. Everything I do is based off of a cloned version of the GitHub repository.

Comment: @BradLarson Understood. I think you've definitely pointed me in the right direction though. I'm gonna investigate conditionally omitting the GPUImage mac framework in the podspec.

Comment: @BradLarson I fixed this issue by adding exclude params to the podspec. You were correct about the source of the problem, so thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by adding these lines to podspec:

```
 s.osx.exclude_files = 'framework/Source/iOS/**/*.{h,m}'
 s.ios.exclude_files = 'framework/Source/Mac/**/*.{h,m}'
```

Fixes pushed to master podspec repo.

Comment: Awesome!  Works for me when applied locally.  I don't see this pushed to the Podspec repo btw -- sure it went through?

Comment: @Ben I submitted a pull request. I have no idea when/if it'll be accepted.